# Finder preview: See file size and date in column view

Tags: finder, mojave

I use Finder mostly in the column view, which has a preview option. This shows a thumbnail of the selected file. Previously this showed file information like a date and file size. I prefer this much over the current view.

How do I get the file size and date info back without having to open the Info window?

Comment: When you're in column view, and you have a single file selected and showing in the preview pane, is there a More (...) button showing? Try scrolling the file's preview pane, or enlarge the entire window itself. The file size & date/timestamp is underneath the More (...) button.

Comment: Thanks, stupid that I never noticed that you could scroll down. My Finder window is never that high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control what is shown in the Preview pane with "Show Preview Options" under the View menu. 
However, these settings seem to apply per-filetype.

You may want to remove the Quick Actions bar, which gets in the way of the file info. (You can still access the Quick Actions on a right-click Contextual menu.)

Comment: I would want to remove the Quick Actions bar. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: As I say: there's a checkbox in Show Preview Options.

Comment: I didn't realise that you can right click on the quick actions bar, because that gives other options than right clicking on the filename.

Answer (score 2):

The file size, creation and modification date information is shown just below the file preview.

[image]

You can scroll vertically over the file preview area or enlarge the Finder window to view the information.