# Improve file-info visibility in Finder's preview pane

Tags: finder, mojave

I find the file information in the preview pane **in column view** is far more useful than the thumbnail.  I wish I did not have to continually resize the Finder window or scroll the preview pane to see the info I'm looking for.

As you can see below, the useful info is hidden in default  size  of Finder's new window under the preview options like rotate etc.

> [image: finder screenshot]

Is there a way to do any of these to achieve the said goal (listed in order of decreasing likelihood!):

- reduce the size of the preview "thumbnail" covered by black here,
- reduce the amount of whitespace(grey here) around the preview "thumbnail" (only significant for landscape thumbnails),
- remove the preview "thumbnail" altogether,
- reorder the content of the preview column(bring file info up and send thumbnail down)?

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/363888/203163) includes the options:

- resizing the Finder in every new window (which is labor intensive).
- Using View menu> Show Preview Options to turn off Quick Actions (which must be done for each file-type, and only reveals a small amount of file info).

Comment: I'm a little confused. What do you mean by Finder Preview Pane? Do you just mean the list of files given by Finder?  if so, there are 4 views to pick from. Which view are you referring to?

Comment: @jmh Ah I thought of adding that.. then went to IPS.SE. It's column view, as in the screenshot and in the yellow box summary too. Other views don't allow to use  "preview options" in View menu, neither do they have preview pane. (that's just the root cause of the former. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, I don't think there is the level of customization in the Finder that you want.

There are "Finder alternatives", like [Path Finder](https://cocoatech.com/#/), which may lay out information in a better way.

The default size of a Finder window can be set as follows:
1. Close all windows.
2. Open a window and make it the size you want.
3. Close it. Now all new windows will be the same size.

(Since Classic MacOS days!)

Comment: Resizing Finder's new window suggestions are welcome too.  Ignore the yellow banner

Comment: The old trick for Finder window sizing was: 1. Close all windows. 2. Open a window and make it the size you want. 3. Close it. Now all new windows will be the same size.

Comment: That's a cool tip! Now I wonder **1** how to windows end up in the small size in the first place? restart? **2** It actually increases the size of the thumbnail too. But it is helpful! Do edit it into the answer.

Comment: As someone who uses Path Finder, it seems like the obvious solution to me. I mean I do also like [Naveed's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370736/126929) as I always liked the list view the best. But getting back to Path Finder, its info module has a collapsible preview and the preview has a max height of about 200px unlike the Finder preview. Not to mention the info can be rearranged: https://youtu.be/Iv9H-D6WCcU — You can sprinkle these modules in other modes too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqUssENRSXs you could add the info module in the list view too...

Comment: @joonas path finder is not free I presume? If it is, it would be one stop for me too.

Comment: @ankii, yea it is a paid app. But at least it is a single payment. I've been using it for 4 years now. It was definitely worth it for me. It does have a 30 day trial. The closest alternative is [Commander One](https://mac.eltima.com/file-manager.html) (freemium)

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer because, although I haven't tried it yet, it looks like Path Finder has a collapsible Preview pane.  And I'll bet that @benwiggy is right that there is no native solution.

Comment: @ankii Regarding setting the default window size: Unfortunately, this is useless if you (like me) like to keep things tidy, frequently having zero or one Finder window open. The result is continually changing the default unintentionally.  I've been bewildered by that method for 30 years.

Comment: Don't forget to send Feedback to Apple, either on their feedback pages or using the Feedback Assistant app. I've suggested that Finder have a feature like Terminal's Window Groups, where you can set windows and tabs up and save them.

Comment: @benwiggy, there is this little app I like to call Path Finder that [does that](http://www.macdrifter.com/2014/07/saved-views-in-path-finder.html), maybe you've heard of it ;) — Sadly native apps tend to get power user features kinda rarely. I was surprised Finder got tabs as "early" as it did...

Comment: @Joonas Not sure what your point is. Path Finder has been mentioned several times. Other apps may have these features, but if you want them in the Finder: send feedback to Apple.

Comment: @benwiggy, just wanted make sure that everyone knows this tab grouping you mentioned is in the app you suggested in the answer. The second half of my comment was just basically me implying vaguely that it's not worth it to send feedback or at the very least it's not worth it to wait for such features... Especially when third party apps have had these features for years.— Oh and first half of that comment was me jonkly saying maybe you've heard of it, knowing full well you were the one who suggested it I  your answer, hence the winking smiley.

Answer (score 1):

Finder has multiple views including ‘List’ view mode. Your required information can be shown in multiple columns.

Finder > View > as List   **⌘2**

[image: Finder List View]

Comment: Could you add screenshot please. I don't understand Details view mode.

Comment: Right. Does it solve the problem? Or are you still looking to hack into Finder App.

Comment: This is no-doubt informative. I didn't know that more columns can be added in List view. Thanks! But I am a long time user of column view. But compromise is the way to go if there's nothing else to do. Also, I just put up the bounty, question belongs to JamesM. They decide the acceptance, I will keep the bounty alive for 3 more days.

Comment: If the goal were only to reveal more information, then the shortest route would be to open a "Get Info" window (⌘I).  For quickly looking through multiple files, ⌥⌘I for an "Inspector" window.  This is less disruptive than switching from Column view to List view.  However, the goal of the original question was to have the information immediately available in Column view.

Comment: Idea is to use the list view on a folder where file info of every next file is required. Opening multiple info windows would be confusing.

Comment: Yea, you tell him, Naveed! _list view is the best..._

Comment: I know list view is not ideal but I was wondering that view might be handy to a specific folder where he’s more interested in custom information. I’ve been using third party finder clones and aware of their benefits and pitfalls.

Comment: One of the arguably downside of too cluttered third party finder apps is that they become frustrating and after using them for few days if you look at original Finder, you get a sigh of relief.

Comment: I love the list view and I can't stand any other view modes, column view especially. Sure you get the info panel there, but every time you open a folder, it expands to the right. So when you're a few folders in you get scrollbars and I just don't see the usefulness of having every single folder open between the starting point and the last folder you opened. I love that in list view I can just expand a folder and stay in the parent folder. Or alternatively actually open a folder. And... If I want to expand or collapse the whole folder tree, I can do that wit the modifier `Alt`.

Comment: Specifically in Path Finder I love that I can expand a folder alias, which is [amazingly useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpY1L.gif)